# Reusing a callback interface across multiple Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, interface, callback, fragment

My desired goal is to have one implemented method in the MainActivity for all fragments I am going to be creating. It's purpose is to allow spawning of another fragment (Ex. Fragment1 is a listview. It calls back to the mainActivity to create a detailedItemFragment. This detailedItemFragment can in turn spawn a fragment with the same callback)

Each fragment contains the same interface description. The callback passes an Id depending on the desired next fragment. My problems begin when I attempt to attach the second callback to the Activity in onAttach(). I get a ClassCastException.

I think this is a conceptual problem with interfaces and that I am not implementing this correctly. For now I will use individual callbacks. My question is is this correct practice and if so why is there a problem on the second fragments onAttach()?

My First Fragment is:

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

public interface OnItemSelected {
    public void launchNewFragment(FragId id);
}
private OnItemSelected callback;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        callback = (OnItemSelected) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement OnItemSelected");
    }
}
```

My Second Fragment is:

```
public class Offer1Fragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

public interface OnItemSelected {
    public void launchNewFragment(FragId id);
}

private OnItemSelected callback;
private Context context;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_offer1, container, false);
    context = getActivity();

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        callback = (OnItemSelected) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnItemSelected");
    }
}
```

My MainActivity implements OnItemSelected and contains this:

```
@Override
public void launchNewFragment(FragId id) {

    fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);

    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch(id) {
        case Offer1:
            fragment = new Offer1Fragment();
            break;

        //Other fragment ids are used to instantiate here as well
    }
    fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

}
```

The error block is:

03-28 10:19:07.552: E/AndroidRuntime(6099): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-28 10:19:07.552: E/AndroidRuntime(6099): java.lang.ClassCastException: ca.test.code.MainActivity@4244bbe0 must implement OnItemSelected
03-28 10:19:07.552: E/AndroidRuntime(6099):     at ca.test.code.fragments.Offer1Fragment.onAttach(Offer1Fragment.java:38)
03-28 10:19:07.552: E/AndroidRuntime(6099):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:844)
03-28 10:19:07.552: E/AndroidRuntime(6099):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057)
03-28 10:19:07.552: E/AndroidRuntime(6099):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
03-28 10:19:07.552: E/AndroidRuntime(6099):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1435)
03-28 10:19:07.552: E/AndroidRuntime(6099):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:441)
03-28 10:19:07.552: E/AndroidRuntime(6099):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
03-28 10:19:07.552: E/AndroidRuntime(6099):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-28 10:19:07.552: E/AndroidRuntime(6099):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-28 10:19:07.552: E/AndroidRuntime(6099):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)

Comment: I suggest posting the relevant part of your code here.

Comment: sounds like a polymorphic issue. code will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you defined two different interfaces named OnItemSelected in both fragments.
So either your activity implements both or even better you just create one interface for both activities

Comment: This was it. Creating two interfaces with the same name and then trying to implement both of them in the same class does not work. Thanks.